# Weird text wrapping problem (wrapfigure, wraptable) - trying to wrap text around an image and a table

Tags: tables, wrapfigure

I'm pretty new to LaTeX - I've done a few very basic homework assignments but this is my first time trying to publish a lab report. I've sort of mickey-moused a template that works but I'm having trouble wrapping text around two figures, a table and an image, at the same time. It seems to only want to wrap one or the other.

Here is the public project file -

https://www.sharelatex.com/project/56198221357a320e5b8c8d5e

The issue I'm having is getting text to wrap around the second image and the table at the same time. You'll probably notice a weird out of place "c" next to the table - once that is deleted the text skips the table entirely and only wraps around the image at the bottom. I've been screwing around with it all day and I haven't been able to figure it out.

```
\lipsum
\begin{wraptable}{l}{90mm}
....
\end{wraptable}
\begin{wrapfigure}
....
\end{wrapfigure}
```

If I put some text between \end{wraptable} and \begin{wrapfigure} then \lipsum wraps fine, albeit with whatever random test I add between the two. When there is no random text, \lipsum either wraps one or the other depending on where it's placed (before or after)

Comment: Welcome! Please make a minimal example showing the problem and post the code here. An external link means your question will not be very useful to others because the content is likely t change.

Comment: In general you should never use ```\\``` in the text. Using it to separate  paragraphs is wrong, use a blank line (and if you really want some vertical space and no indentation, add `\usepackage{parskip}`. Second, rather than enumrating figures manually, use `\caption{caption of figure}\label{descriptive label}`, and use `\ref{descriptive label}` to add a cross reference. Third, use `\ln`, not `ln`, them it will be typeset properly. Fourth, why not use `\section` instead of the manually formatted section headings? This allows you to set the formatting and numbering globally. (ctd.)

Comment: Fifth, you can use `\vspace{<length>}`/`\vspace*{<length>}` to add some vertical space in your titlepage. The starred version will also work on the top of pages. Six, look at the `siunitx` package for typesetting units and numbers with units.

Answer (score 2):

Wrapping something should be in a paragraph. Hence critical part of your file should be (corrected in your file now):

```
\lipsum
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{.525\textwidth} %this figure will be at the right
    \includegraphics[width=.525\textwidth]{T vs R - tungsten filament.png}
    \begin{center}
Figure 3
\end{center}
\end{wrapfigure}

%\lipsum
```

(Observe the position of `\lipsum).

BTW: Replacing all text `\\`'s by blank lines would help (La)TeX to correct dividing paragraphs into lines.

**Edit** New version:

```
$\,$
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{.525\textwidth} %this figure will be at the right
    \includegraphics[width=.525\textwidth]{T vs R - tungsten filament.png}
    \begin{center}
Figure 3
\end{center}
\end{wrapfigure}

\lipsum
```

Comment: I did that at first, but do you notice how now the second image is pushed all the way down to the bottom of \lipsum? That's what I meant about only wrapping one or the other.

Comment: i.e. I want the second image directly underneath the table

Comment: @Brendan Hence the suggestion of dividing your text into real paragraphs first. Please add critical part of your file here, as MWE, to help future users with similar problems.

Comment: @Brendan See new version in your file.

Comment: What is $\,$ and why does it go back to behaving the same way when I delete it? Also, why does the table move up on top of the table when I delete \lipsum and add normal text?